# How to workaround java 6 ssl error

Tags: java, ssl, https, resttemplate

I'm stuck in a Java 6 environment. I cannot modify the JRE configuration. I am trying to access a specific service like this:`new RestTemplate().postForObject("https://someService.com","hello", String.class);`

I get this error `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024`

probably because  the parameter provided by the service is larger than 1024. How do I work around this?

I have no control over the service I am trying to access. I cannot accept server based solutions.

Comment: just a sidenote : JRE6/JDK6 are deprecated, support for most of the v6 API has already been dropped. There is literally no reason to keep using it since 8 is mostly downwards compatible to 6

Comment: @specializt Accuracy please. 'Support for most of the v6 API' has not been 'dropped'. It is *all* still supported *in Java 8.* Support for *JRE 6* has ended except for some paying customers.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself in your own sentence.

Comment: @specializt Not in the least. You're confusing the API, which is a specification, with the JRE, which is a product.

Comment: Not in the least - the JRE is a *software bundle*; there are bundles from Oracle and also open-source bundles. The JRE is a collection of API libraries and also platform-specific binaries (the entire JVM, for example). Some parts of the v6 API have already been deleted or changed into incompatibility (out of necessity), java apps which rely on those will not work with the v8 API - be it JRE or JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options, depending on a number of details you didn't specify:

- If you can change code on the client, and the server accepts plain-RSA key-exchange i.e. not DHE or ECDHE and thus no Forward Secrecy which many people demand today, change the client to disable all ciphersuites whose name contains `_DHE_` . (To be safe, disable `_DH_` static suites also, although almost no one uses them and it's very unlikely your server would.)

  If `RestTemplate` (or something it calls you control) directly creates the SSL socket and does HTTP over it, at that creation call `.getEnabledCipherSuites()` to get the current array, create a new array with the undesired items excluded, and `.setEnabledCipherSuites()`.

  If it uses `URLConnection` on the `https:` URL, create an `SSLSocketFactory` that wraps the standard one and modifies the (created) sockets as above, and make that factory the default factory for `HttpsURLConnection`.

  If it uses something else, like Apache httpclient, there is probably an equivalent technique or setting, but I don't know it.
- If you can change code on the client and add a library, and the server accepts ECDHE key-exchange, get the bcprov jar from https://www.bouncycastle.org and put it somewhere  in your classpath, and at the beginning of your app do `java.security.Security.addProvider ( new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider () )`. This works because Java6 *JSSE* supports the ECHDE ciphersuites *if* there is a provider for ECC primitives, which Java6 does not include; Java**7** adds SunEC for this. BC provides a whole bunch of things you mostly don't need but including among them ECC primitives.
- If the server accepts HTTP-no-S and that's okay with you, use `http:`. You might be able to still secure the transport by running over an SSH tunnel or VPN or such, depending on the server.
- If you need HTTPS and you can install software at the client (or a machine connected by a physically secure LAN), install stunnel from https://www.stunnel.org and configure it to listen on a local port you choose and connect with SSL to the real server name/address and port, and have your (real) client connect http-no-s to the stunnel port on localhost or verynearhost. stunnel then wraps this HTTP in SSL/TLS making it HTTPS.

Note the first two options get around the Java6 (and 7, fixed in 8) limitation on integer Diffie-Hellman key-exchange, but they do not change the Java6 limitation to TLSv1.0 protocol. A server that is using integer-DH parameters over 1024 bits may be because it is subject to strict security requirements (which may or may not actually be necessary, but if you don't control the service you don't get to decide), and many such security requirements discourage TLSv1.0 today and may well prohibit it soon, in which case Java6 is flat out of luck.
And if there are security requirements, option 3 may not be acceptable either, leaving only 4 (stunnel).

Answer (score 0):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_faq.html#javadh

> Beginning with version 2.4.7, mod_ssl will use DH parameters which
>   include primes with lengths of more than 1024 bits. Java 7 and earlier
>   limit their support for DH prime sizes to a maximum of 1024 bits,
>   however.
>
> If your Java-based client aborts with exceptions such as
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair and
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be
>   multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive), and
>   httpd logs tlsv1 alert internal error (SSL alert number 80) (at
>   LogLevel info or higher), you can either rearrange mod_ssl's cipher
>   list with SSLCipherSuite (possibly in conjunction with
>   SSLHonorCipherOrder), or you can use custom DH parameters with a
>   1024-bit prime, which will always have precedence over any of the
>   built-in DH parameters.

Comment: Note that this solution applies at the server, and assumes the server is running Apache HTTPD.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I have edited the question to  clarify that this is not going to work